# Getting the running time of Xen guest domain

Tags: arm64, xen, hypervisor

I need the Xen domain to see the times it was running. I tried rtems and Linux domains on xen4.11, and on both of them, the uptime shows times when the domain was not running on the vCPU.

Based on
[this link](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102142/0100/Virtualizing-the-generic-timers), virtualizing the generic timers in AArch64

> A hypervisor could use the offset register to present a virtual count that only shows time the vCPU was running.

```
Virtual Count (CNTVCT_EL0) = Physical Count (CNTPCT_EL0) - <offset> (CNTVOFF_EL2)
```

[image]

I changed the value of **virt_timer_base.offset** and **CNTVOFF_EL2** in `virt_timer_restore` function but it did not work.

I would appreciate any help on how I can achieve it in Xen.

Where and how I should change the CNTVOFF_EL2 value?